# Ion-slides no se muestran de manera correcta en algunos dispositivos iOS

Tags: angular, ionic, ios

Estoy tratando de subir mi app a la App Store, pero me la rechazaron por que en algunos dispositivos no se muestran los ion-slides de manera correcta.

Pareciera que el problema es la versión de iOS.

Mal mostrada - iPad 9th Gen (iOS 15.0)
iPad (9th generation)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mal mostrada - iPad Air 4th Gen (iOS 15.0)
iPad Air (4th generation)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mostrada sin problemas - iPadPro 11-inch (iOS 12.4)
iPadPro 11-Inch 12.4
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien tiene idea de por que pasa esto?

Ya intenté migrar también los ion-slides a Swiper pero tuve la misma problemática

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: entonces el código hay que adivínarlo???